# VHDL FSM not working?

Tags: simulation, vhdl, state-machine, intel-fpga

In the picture you can see that when key(1)=0 and clock rising edge, SELECAO goes to 01. But after one clock cycle, it goes to 00 (it should stay at 01)

The FSM simulation works okay when alone, but it fails whenever I try it with the whole system.

Can you find a problem in the following vhdl code?

[image: simulation]

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FSMctrl is port (
    Clk, Rst, Enter : in std_logic;
    operacao: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    selecao: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    Enable_1, Enable_2: out std_logic
);
end FSMctrl;

architecture FSM_beh of FSMctrl is
    type states is (S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7);
    signal EA, PE: states;
    signal clock: std_logic;
    signal reset: std_logic;
begin
    clock <= Clk;
    reset <= Rst;

    P1: process (clock, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '0' then
            EA <= S0;
        elsif clock'event and clock = '1' then
            EA <= PE;
        end if;
    end process;

    --adicionar operacao na sensitivity list em 31/10 pois a compilacao deu um
    --alerta
    P2: process (EA, Enter)
    begin
        case EA is
            when S0 =>
                if Enter = '1' then--teste
                    --enable_1 <= '1';
                    PE <= S0;
                else
                    PE <= S1;
                end if;
                Enable_1 <= '0';
                Enable_2 <= '0';

            when S1 =>
                if Enter = '0' then
                    PE <= S1;    --ele deve esperar soltar o botao
                else
                    PE <= S2;
                end if;
                Enable_1 <= '1';
                Enable_2 <= '0';

            when S2 => -- Operador
                Enable_1 <= '0';
                Enable_2 <= '0';

                --   PE <= S3 when operacao = "00" else
                --   S4 when operacao = "01" else
                --   S5 when operacao = "10" else
                --   S6;
                if operacao = "00" then
                    PE <= S3; -- Fazer soma
                elsif operacao = "01" then
                    PE <= S4; -- Fazer subtracao
                elsif operacao = "10" then
                    PE <= S5; --fazer divisao
                elsif operacao = "11" then
                    PE <= S6;--fazer produto
                end if;

            --01/11: movendo atribuicoes de selecao para dentro da condicao enter=0 em S3, S4, enter=1 nos S5 e S6
            when S3 =>
                if Enter = '1' then
                    PE <= S3;
                else
                    PE <= S7;
                    Selecao <= "00";
                end if;

            when S4 =>
                if Enter = '1' then
                    PE <= S4;
                else
                    PE <= S7;
                    Selecao <= "01";
                end if;

            when S5 =>
                if Enter = '0' then --verificar aqui
                    PE <= S5; --do S5 pro S6??? deveria ser pro S7?
                else
                    PE <= S0;
                    Selecao <= "10";
                end if;
                Enable_1 <= '0'; --adicionado (SANDBOX)
                Enable_2 <= '1'; --adicionado (SANDBOX)

            when S6 =>
                if Enter = '0' then --adicionado um looping para esperar o Enter ser solto
                    PE <= S6;
                else
                    PE <= S0;
                    Selecao <= "11";
                end if;
                Enable_1 <= '0';
                Enable_2 <= '1';

            when S7 =>
                Enable_1 <= '0';
                Enable_2 <= '1';
                if Enter = '0' then --adicionado um looping para esperar o Enter ser solto
                    PE <= S7;
                else
                    PE <= S0;
                end if;
        end case;
    end process;
end FSM_beh; -- fim da architecture
```

Comment: Format it better if you want people to read it. It is also a good example why the single-process style of state machine is more likely to work. : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463359/vhdl-state-machine-differences-for-synthesization?rq=1

Comment: operacao is missing from the sensitivity list for P2, contrary to the comment about October 31.  Without seeing more of your design the names in the waveform don't relate to your FSMctrl.  I also can't help but wonder if the enter key doesn't need De-bouncing. And @Brian, I totally don't get why this is an example of why a single process state machine is more likely to work. states, Estado Atual, and Proximo Estado are are all defined in the architecture declarative region common to both processes. The portion of the design revealed is a simple Moore machine.

Comment: @David : That sensitivity list problem (error? deliberate? my Portuguese isn't up to it) is exactly why I prefer the single process. Thanks for expanding EA, PE! And while you're right about debouncing, I'm not sure that'll help a simulation...

Comment: more details added below

Comment: As an aside note, don't do assignments to clock:  "clock <= Clk;"  These lead to clocks that are not delta cycle aligned and are problematic if different designs have different delta cycle misalignments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the bad formating, I'm still pretty new and I think I got it how the ctrl+k works, I'll try adding pictures to it without link (thanks sharth). So, this code works as said when we use the RTL simulation, as follows:

[image]

As you can see, "selecao" should keep "01", and it does!
I have no clue at all why this is happening, I suppose this is a problem in the FSM itself, else, where would it be?

The steps are:
operacao has to be "01" in this case, so selecao would be the same
start: enter='1' -> enter='0' -> enter='1' -> enter='0' -> enter="1"

Thanks for the support I've been having with my other issue(post)!

Comment: http://puu.sh/5l3l3.png Here you can see that when enter(key1) goes to '0', selecao goes to "01" immediately. However, as soon as the state goes from S4 to S7, selecao changes back to "00". (this is the FSM with the rest of the system). I really can't see why, since S7 doesn't assign any value to selecao...