# VHDL: Mealy machine and button press detection

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Hi I'm a bit confused about the implementation of Mealy state machine using VHDL. My current work is like this:

```
process(clk, rst)
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        state <= s1;
    elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
        state <= next_state;
    end if;
end process;
```

and another process like this:

```
process(state, op)
begin
    case state is
    when s1 =>
    ...some implementation
end process;
```

And now the problem is: I need to detect the press of the button from the user, but I'm not sure where to put it. Should it be inside the first process or the second process? Besides, I also looked through the following guide: [implement state machine in FPGA](http://www.rs-online.com/designspark/electronics/knowledge-item/how-to-implement-state-machines-in-your-fpga), is it okay to use just one process for the Mealy machine as shown on the webpage? If it is so then I think the work will be easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in the second process. The first process is only used to change states and the `next_state` is also calculated in the second.

There are several ways to write FSMs and people tend to favour one or the other for various reasons. Pick the one that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot design a Mealy state machine with only one process. Even Moore state machines, in most cases, cannot be modelled with only one process.

A state machine always has a state register which **must** be modelled with a synchronous process. That is, a process which sensitivity list contains only the clock (and set or reset signals if they are asynchronous).

Every output of a synchronous process will synthesize as the output of a register because its value changes only on an edge of the clock (plus states of asynchronous set or reset if any). So, you cannot describe the outputs of a Mealy state machine in the same synchronous process as the state register. If you were doing so, it would not be a Mealy machine any more because its outputs would not combinationally depend on the inputs.

For Moore machines, things are a bit more subtle but, except in very exceptional cases, you also need at least two processes. When I write "process", I include processes short-hands like concurrent signal assignments, concurrent procedure calls or component/entity instantiations.

To make it simple: VHDL modelling for synthesis is straightforward if you have a clear view of the hardware you want.

- Draw a block diagram of your hardware with registers and combinatorial parts clearly identified.
- Draw bubbles enclosing hardware elements, one bubble per process, respecting the rule that if a bubble contains a register, all its outputs **must** be register outputs.

The synchronous processes are those enclosing registers. Their code is **exactly**:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    <your code>
  end if;
end process;
```

Put your code in `<your code>`, **never** put code elsewhere. If you have asynchronous set or reset the code **must** be something like:

```
process(clk, reset)
begin
  if reset = '1' then
    <initialize outputs>
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    <your code>
  end if;
end process;
```

The other processes are combinatorial processes. List all their entering signals (INPUTS) and output signals (OUTPUTS). The code **must** be:

```
process(INPUTS)
begin
  <your code>
end process;
```

with the constraint that each OUTPUT signal **must** be assigned a value in **every** execution of the process. The best way to guarantee this is to start the process with a default assignment of **all** OUTPUTS.

That's all. Draw and code what you see. Bonus: every arrow crossing the border of one of your process-bubbles is a signal that you will have to declare unless it is already a primary input or output of your design.

Exercise: draw the block diagram of a Mealy state machine and understand why it cannot be modelled with one single process. Understand also why it can always be modelled with two processes, even if it is not necessarily desirable. Finally, try to identify the rare cases where a Moore state machine can be modelled with one process only.

Comment: What things are called is probably not terribly important but what do you call those common single process things containing a state signal and displayed in the reference?

Comment: The code displayed on this web page is not the code of a Mealy state machine because all outputs are assigned in a synchronous process, that is, are outputs of a register. There is thus no combinatorial path between inputs and outputs, which is the characteristic of a Mealy machine. What is described is a Moore machine and its state is the `(op, current_state)` combination.

Comment: My point is that with your definition of what a Moore FSM is they are not at all exceptional and the real state differs from the state signal in the code. That's why many like to think of this as a Mealy FSM with registered outputs. Again, the more important issue is the pros and cons of various constructs, not the name. That has been discussed before on SO, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463359/vhdl-state-machine-differences-for-synthesization

Comment: Interesting discussion but, in my humble opinion, it misses the most important point which is the ever increasing critical path when you chain Mealy machines. Not a matter of coding style, a matter of propagation delays. Thus my preference for a clear definition of Mealy / Moore based on combinational path or not between inputs and outputs. Moreover, logic synthesizers completely transform the logic and what is a registered output in the VHDL code becomes a part of the state. So, what you can consider a registered outputs Mealy is, at the end, a true Moore machine.

Comment: IMHO = You are wrong ;-) But I do agree with you on not having long combinatorial paths. That's why people use one process state machines. They will register all outputs and it avoids other problems with two processes FSMs as discussed in the older SO thread I linked. Since there is no commonly used definition of Mealy and Moore those names can't be used to determine if good design practices have been used or not.